# views custom link like page more link

Tags: views, navigation

I want to add a custom link at the end of the loop of my view just like Pager More Link do. But I want to create a custom link. What I've tried so far:

I have created a `Custom Text` field, rewrote it to a link that I want and made it exclude from display. Then I group my this field and with css I place it where I want it. The only problem is that this grouped field is displayed with an `<h3>` tag that I don't want.

Is there any way to group field but not in tag `<h3><h4>...` or there is a module or something which can give me a option to create a link similar to the pager more link but with a custom url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a `Text area` view footer field?

[image: footer field]

You can set it to full HTML and just add an HTML anchor there. Optionally there is checkbox to 'Display even if the view has no results'.

This adds a custom link below your view.

Comment: I know it. I know i do this before. Spend like all day to search an obvious think. Thanks mate.